# Mixing py.test and doctests

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

Many of my tests are written in py.test where it makes sense:

```
def test_some_function():
    assert some_function() == 42
```

Some other user directed functions end up having doctests because they will show up in the documentation:

```
def snub(k):
    """
    Snub will deflarg your booblebum.

    >>> snub(10)
    20
    >>> snub('tomorrow')
    'carrot'

    :param any k: The transspace to deflarg.
    :returs any:
    """    
    # ...
```

I know that with `--doctest-modules` I can get pytest to run the doctests but I have not yet found a way of running all tests at the same time.

What I want is something like:

all_tests.py

```
from my_module import snub  # now this should be enough to run the doctests

def test_some_function():
    assert some_function() == 42
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this? Am I missing something?

I would also gladly use some kind of generator where I can input the functions that have doctests to run.

Comment: Why do you think you need `all_tests.py`? Running `pytest --doctest-modules` will run all - doctests and pytests. Have I missed something?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk How does it find all tests if the tests are under `project/tests` and the sources are under `project/src`?

Comment: And the documentation hints that `--doctest-modules` will test ALL modules doctests, not just the ones in my project...

Comment: Just run `pytest --doctest-modules` in `project` directory - it scans all subdirectories, so `tests` and `src` are included. Parent directories won't be scanned, so other projects are safe.

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk, your comment answers the question. Rewrite it as an actual answer, so that RedX can accept it, and readers can upvote it.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt Thanks for ur comment, I was waiting for OP reply because I had felt it's not the main problem

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt The answer does not meet,my requireements completely. Only few modulex in my project are written with doctests and can be imported freely. Other modules cannot be imported on all systzems and therefore `--doctest-modules does not work for me

Comment: Just specify the modules and directories you want to test as an argument to pytest. `pytest --doctest-modules path/to/module.py /path/to/directory` That way you will not import the modules that can not be imported by the test script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your tests in a separate folder, than your python module, as in the following structure:

```
my-project
├── mylib
│   └── mymod.py
└── tests
    └── test_mymod.py
```

The key to make pytest discover everything, is to give it enough information. You can simply specify both folders on the command line for discovery:

```
pytest --doctest-modules mylib tests
```

To make this a bit more comfortable you can set the `testpaths` config-variable for pytest, and also include the doctest argument by default. An example `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--doctest-modules"
testpaths = [
    "tests",
    "mylib",
]
```

pytest will recursively walk through the folders to discover the tests.